# Add a dynamic sequence number in a DIV class using PHP

Tags: php, loops, foreach

This is a PHP version which repeats the DIVs. I want to add a dynamic class to the ClassX. X being a dynamic sequence number. Something like Class1, Class2, etc..

```
<div class="row">
    <?php foreach ($this->fields as $field) { ?>
        <div class="col-sm-5 col-xs-12 ClassX">
            <?php echo $field[0]; ?>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
            <?php echo $field[1]; ?>
        </div>
    <?php } ?>
</div>
```

The Output to be something like this:

```
<div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-5 col-xs-12 Class1">text</div>
        <div class="col-sm-6 col-xs-12">text</div>
        <div class="col-sm-5 col-xs-12 Class2">text</div>
        <div class="col-sm-6 col-xs-12">text</div>
        <div class="col-sm-5 col-xs-12 Class3">text</div>
        <div class="col-sm-6 col-xs-12">text</div>
        <div class="col-sm-5 col-xs-12 Class4">text</div>
        <div class="col-sm-6 col-xs-12">text</div>
</div>
```

How do I add that class to change dynamically in a sequence?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here you go `<?= ++$n` is similar to `<?php echo ++$n;` and you don't need short tags enabled

```
<div class="row">
    <?php $n=0; foreach ($this->fields as $field) { ?>
        <div class="col-sm-5 col-xs-12 Class<?= ++$n ?>">
            <?= $field[0]; ?>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
            <?= $field[1]; ?>
        </div>
    <?php } ?>
</div>
```